# Bad to return method data to another method?

Tags: methods

I'm wondering if it is bad practice to call a method with data from another method.  It seems to me it should be ok as it saves an extra instantiation. I'm working with static data for automated testing.

I have a class DefaultValues which contains default values that should appear on screen I am testing.

```
public static Dictionary<string,string> GetBackOfficeDefaults()
{
     return new Dictionary<string, string>{
           { "currency", Currency}, { "wholeNumber", WholeNumber}, { "number", Number},
           { "date", Date}, { "comboBox", ComboBox}, { "memo", Memo}, { "text",Text}
     };
}
```

So I have a method that receives this dictionary which determines which data it will be testing.

```
VerifyCustomFields.RequiredDefaultValues(DefaultedValues.GetBackOfficeDefaults());
```

so should I be creating a new variable and then passing it or is it ok to simply call a method as an argument. Is this way below safer?

```
Dictionary<string, string> values = DefaultedValues.GetBackOfficeDefaults();
VerifyCustomFields.RequiredDefaultValues(values);
```

Thanks in advance for any help.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know the structure of your project, but focus on your question basically using a method to create an object is a design pettern called Factory Method, so this is not a bad practice, but I don't know the entire structure of your project so I can't tellyou if it is well implemented or not, but you can check in this web for furter information: 
https://sourcemaking.com/design-patterns-and-tips